# Cutting algorithm of two dimensional board

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

I have problem with my homework.

Given a board of dimensions `m` x `n` is given, cut this board into rectangular pieces with the best total price. A matrix gives the price for each possible board size up through the original, uncut board.

Consider a `2 x 2` board with the price matrix:

```
3 4

3 6
```

We have a constant cost for each cutting for example `1`.

Piece of length `1 x 1` is worth `3`.

Horizontal piece of length `1 x 2` is worth `4`.

Vertical piece of length `1 x 2` is worth `3`.

Whole board is worth `6`.

For this example, the **optimal profit is 9**, because we cut board into `1 x 1` pieces. Each piece is worth `3` and we done a `3` cut, so `4 x 3` - `3 x 1` = `9`.

Second example:

```
1 2

3 4
```

Now I have to consider all the solutions:

- `4` `1x1` pieces is worth `4x1 - (cost of cutting) 3x1 = 1`
- `2` horizontal `1x2 is worth 2x2 - (cost of cutting) 1x1 = 3`
- `2` vertical `1x2 is worth 3x2 - (cost of cutting) 1x1 = 5` **-> best optimal profit**
- `1` horizontal `1x2 + 2 x (1x1) pieces is worth 2 + 2 - (cost of cutting) 2 = 2`
- `1` vertical `1x2 + 2 x (1x1) pieces is worth 3 + 2 - (cost of cutting) 2 = 3`

I've read a lot about rod cutting algorithm but I don't have any idea how to bite this problem.
Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Try to ask in other **STACK EXCHANGE COMMUNITIES** such as "Academia"

Comment: I have added second example to main post.

Answer (score 2):

I did this in Python.  The algorithm is

- `best_val` = value of current board
- check each horizontal and vertical cut for better value

  - for cut point <= half the current dimension (if none, return initial value)
  - recur on the two boards formed
  - if sum of values > `best_val`
  - ... `best_val` = that sum
  - ... record cut point and direction
- return result: best_val, cut point, and direction

I'm not sure what you'll want for return values; I gave back the best value and tree of boards.  For your second example, this is

```py
(5, [[2, 1], [2, 1]])
```

Code, with debugging traces (`indent` and the labeled `print`s):

```py
indent = ""
indent_len = 3

value = [[1, 2],
         [3, 4]]

def best_cut(high, wide):
    global indent
    print indent, "ENTER", high, wide
    indent += " " * indent_len

    best_val = value[high-1][wide-1]
    print indent, "Default", best_val
    cut_vert = None
    cut_val = best_val
    cut_list = []

    # Check horizontal cuts
    for h_cut in range(1, 1 + high // 2):
        print indent, "H_CUT", h_cut
        cut_val1, cut_list1 = best_cut(h_cut, wide)
        cut_val2, cut_list2 = best_cut(high - h_cut, wide)
            cut_val = cut_val1 + cut_val2

        if cut_val > best_val:
            cut_list = [cut_list1, cut_list2]
            print indent, "NEW H", h_cut, cut_val, cut_list
            best_val = cut_val
            cut_vert = False
            best_h = h_cut

    # Check vertical cuts
    for v_cut in range(1, 1 + wide // 2):
        print indent, "V_CUT", v_cut
        cut_val1, cut_list1 = best_cut(high, v_cut)
        cut_val2, cut_list2 = best_cut(high, wide - v_cut)
        cut_val = cut_val1 + cut_val2

        if cut_val > best_val:
            cut_list = [cut_list1, cut_list2]
            print indent, "NEW V", v_cut, cut_val, cut_list
            best_val = cut_val
            cut_vert = True
            best_v = v_cut

    # Return result of best cut
    # Remember to subtract the cut cost
    if cut_vert is None:
        result = best_val  , [high, wide]
    elif cut_vert:
        result = best_val-1, cut_list
    else:
        result = best_val-1, cut_list

    indent = indent[indent_len:]
    print indent, "LEAVE", cut_vert, result
    return result

print best_cut(2, 2)
```

Output (profit and cut sizes) for each of the two tests:

```py
(9, [[[1, 1], [1, 1]], [[1, 1], [1, 1]]])

(5, [[2, 1], [2, 1]])
```

Comment: I need to get a maximum profit of cutting board. One board we can cut it into small different squares or rectangles depending on price minus all cost per each cuts. For first example we have total profit 9 and for the second 5.

Comment: Right.  This gives a profit of 5 for the second; I didn't run the other test.

Answer (score 1):

Let `f(h,w)` represent the best total price achievable for a board with height `h` and width `w` with cutting price `c`. Then

```
f(h,w) = max(
  price_matrix(h, w),
  f(i, w) + f(h - i, w) - c,
  f(h, j) + f(h, w - j) - c
)
for i = 1 to floor(h / 2)
for j = 1 to floor(w / 2)
```

Here's a bottom-up example in JavaScript that returns the filled table given the price matrix. The answer would be in the bottom right corner.

```js
function f(prices, cost){
  var m = new Array(prices.length);

  for (let i=0; i<prices.length; i++)
    m[i] = [];

  for (let h=0; h<prices.length; h++){
    for (let w=0; w<prices[0].length; w++){

      m[h][w] = prices[h][w];

      if (h == 0 && w == 0)
        continue;

      for (let i=1; i<(h+1>>1)+1; i++)
        m[h][w] = Math.max(
          m[h][w],
          m[i-1][w] + m[h-i][w] - cost
        );

      for (let i=1; i<(w+1>>1)+1; i++)
        m[h][w] = Math.max(
          m[h][w],
          m[h][i-1] + m[h][w-i] - cost
        );
    }
  }

  return m;
}

$('#submit').click(function(){
  let prices = JSON.parse($('#input').val());
  let result = f(prices, 1);
  let str = result.map(line => JSON.stringify(line)).join('<br>');
  $('#output').html(str);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="input">[[3, 4],
[3, 6]]</textarea>
<p><button type="button" id="submit">Submit</button></p>
<div id="output"><div>
```

Comment: Tell me why did you use bitwise operator in for loop?

Comment: @Tetsu `x >> 1` is the same as `floor(x / 2)`

Comment: Then why do you cut high and wide at half?

Comment: @Tetsu if we cut `w = 10` at `3`, we get `(3, 7)`. If we cut `w = 10` at `7`, we get `(7, 3)`. They are the same and we want to avoid double-counting.

Answer (score 0):

**Some thoughts on the problem rather than an answer:**

It was a long time ago i studied dynamic programming, but i wrote up the following pseudo code which is think is O(n^2):

```
// 'Board'-class not included

val valueOfBoards: HashMap<Board, int>

fun cutBoard(b: Board, value: int) : int {

    if (b.isEmpty()) return 0
     if (valueOfBoards[b] > value) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        valueOfBoards[b] = value
    }

    int maxValue = Integer.MIN_VALUE

    for (Board piece : b.getPossiblePieces()) {
        val (cuttingCost, smallerBoard) = b.cutOffPiece(piece)
        val valueGained: int = piece.getPrice() - cuttingCost

        maxValue = Max(maxValue, valueGained + cutBoard(smallerBoard, value + valueGained))
    }

    return maxValue;
}
```

The board class is not trivially implemented, here is some elaboration:

```
// returns all boards which fits in the current board
// for the initial board this will be width*height subboards
board.getPossiblePieces() 


// returns a smaller board and the cutting cost of the cut
// I can see this becoming complex, depends on how one chooses to represent the board.
board.cutOffPiece(piece: Board)
```

It is not clear to me at the moment if `cutOffPiece()` breaks the algorithm in that you do not know how to optimally cut. I think since the algorithm will proceed from larger pieces to smaller pieces at some point it will be fine.

I tried to solve the re computation of sub problems (identical boards) by storing results in something like `HashMap<Board, price>` and comparing the new board with the stored best price before proceeding.

Answer (score 0):

According to your answers I've prepared bottom-up and top-down implementation.

Bottom-up:

```
function bottomUp($high, $wide, $matrix){
    $m = [];

    for($h = 0; $h < $high; $h++){
        for($w = 0; $w < $wide; $w++){
           $m[$h][$w] = $matrix[$h][$w];

            if($h == 0 && $w == 0){
                continue;
            }

            for($i = 1; $i < ($h + 1 >> 1) + 1; $i++){
                $m[$h][$w] = max(
                    $m[$h][$w],
                    $m[$i - 1][$w] + $m[$h - $i][$w] - CUT_COST
                );
            }

            for($i = 1; $i < ($w + 1 >> 1) + 1; $i++){
                $m[$h][$w] = max(
                    $m[$h][$w],
                    $m[$h][$i - 1] + $m[$h][$w - $i] - CUT_COST
                );
            }            
        }        
    }

    return $m[$high-1][$wide-1];
}
```

Top-down:

```
function getBestCut($high, $wide, $matrix){
    global $checked;

    if(isset($checked[$high][$wide])){
        return $checked[$high][$wide];
    }

    $bestVal = $matrix[$high-1][$wide-1];
    $cutVert = CUT_VERT_NONE;
    $cutVal = $bestVal;
    $cutList = [];

    for($hCut = 1; $hCut < 1 + floor($high/2); $hCut++){
        $result1 = getBestCut($hCut, $wide, $matrix);
        $cutVal1 = $result1[0];
        $cutList1 = $result1[1];
        $result2 = getBestCut($high - $hCut, $wide, $matrix);
        $cutVal2 = $result2[0];
        $cutList2 = $result2[1];        
        $cutVal = $cutVal1 + $cutVal2;

        if($cutVal > $bestVal){
            $cutList = [$cutList1, $cutList2];
            $bestVal = $cutVal;
            $cutVert = CUT_VERT_FALSE;
            $bestH = $hCut;
        }

        $checked[$hCut][$wide] = $result1;
        $checked[$high - $hCut][$wide] = $result2;
    }

    for($vCut = 1; $vCut < 1 + floor($wide/2); $vCut++){
        $result1 = getBestCut($hCut, $vCut, $matrix);
        $cutVal1 = $result1[0];
        $cutList1 = $result1[1];
        $result2 = getBestCut($high, $wide - $vCut, $matrix);
        $cutVal2 = $result2[0];
        $cutList2 = $result2[1];        
        $cutVal = $cutVal1 + $cutVal2;   

        if($cutVal > $bestVal){
            $cutList = [$cutList1, $cutList2];
            $bestVal = $cutVal;
            $cutVert = CUT_VERT_TRUE;
            $bestH = $vCut;
        }      

        $checked[$hCut][$vCut] = $result1;
        $checked[$high][$wide - $vCut] = $result2;        
    }

    if($cutVert == CUT_VERT_NONE){
        $result = [$bestVal, [$high, $wide]];
    }else if($cutVert == CUT_VERT_TRUE){
        $result = [$bestVal - CUT_COST, $cutList];
    }else{
        $result = [$bestVal - CUT_COST, $cutList];
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Please tell me are they correct implementation of this method?

I wonder if time complexity is `O(m^2*n^2)` in top-down method?