# 2-dimensional cutting rod algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

I have an assignment to solve using dynamic programming the following problem:

There is a rectangular sheet and a set of rectangular elements of given dimensions and value. The task is to divide the sheet into elements of given dimensions, so that the sum of values of the elements is maximum. Find this sum and a tree of consequent cuts.

There are following conditions:

- It is NOT possible to rotate the given elements.
- It is possible to cut out unlimited number of certain types of
  elements.
- It is possible that some parts of the sheet will remain unused.
- The only possible way to cut the sheet is by a straight
  line, so that you again obtain two smaller rectangles.

*The problem is solved. Solution can be found below.*

==========================================================================

I understand the problem for one dimension, which comes to the rod cutting problem. You divide the rod into the smallest possible pieces, take the first one and check if you can build it with the given segments. Remember the weight you'll get with building the part this way and move on to a bigger part containing the previous one. You go back by the length of the segment you're trying at the moment and check if using this segment plus the weight of the previously build part will make up to better sum of the weight for the current part.

Supposedly, the cutting wood problem is no different, but you add the 2-dimension, additional loop somewhere in the middle. Unfortunately, I can't imagine how to store the values and how to go back for the 2-dimensions.

I've tried doing like:
1. Loop on one dimension
2. Loop on second dimension
3. Loop on all the segments you can use
4. Check if you can fit the current segment depending on 1. and 2.
5. If yes, go back the length of the segment to see if weight of the segment + what's stored there gives you a greater result; do the same for the width
6. Store the result in the cell you're currently on
7. Go through the array and find the greatest result

Here is the code I produced after many debugging tries:

```
        public int Cut((int length, int width) sheet, (int length, int width, int price)[] elements, out Cut cuts)
    {
            int[,] tmpSheetArr = new int[sheet.length + 1, sheet.width + 1];

            for (int i = 1; i < tmpSheetArr.GetLength(0); i++)
            {
                for (int j = 1; j < tmpSheetArr.GetLength(1); j++)
                {
                    tmpSheetArr[i, j] = Int32.MinValue;
                }
            }

            for (int i = 1; i < tmpSheetArr.GetLength(0); i++)    //columns
            {
                for (int j = 1; j < tmpSheetArr.GetLength(1); j++)    //rows
                {
                    for (int e = 0; e < elements.Length; e++)
                    {
                        (int length, int width, int price) elem = elements[e];
                        if (i >= elem.length && j >= elem.width)
                        {
                            int tmpJ, tmpI, tmpVal;
                            tmpJ = j - elem.width;
                            tmpI = i;
                            while (0 < tmpI)
                            {
                                if(tmpI > i - elem.length && tmpI <= i && tmpJ > j - elem.width && tmpJ <= j)
                                {
                                    tmpJ -= 1;
                                    if (-1 == tmpJ)
                                    {
                                        tmpJ = tmpSheetArr.GetLength(1) - 1;
                                        tmpI -= 1;
                                    }
                                    continue;
                                }

                                tmpVal = tmpSheetArr[tmpI, tmpJ] == Int32.MinValue ? 0 : tmpSheetArr[tmpI, tmpJ];  
                                if (tmpSheetArr[i, j] < elem.price + tmpVal)
                                {
                                    tmpSheetArr[i, j] = elem.price + tmpVal;
                                }

                                tmpJ -= 1;
                                if(-1 == tmpJ)
                                {
                                    tmpJ = tmpSheetArr.GetLength(1) - 1;
                                    tmpI -= 1;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            int tmpMax = 0;
            for (int i = 1; i < tmpSheetArr.GetLength(0); i++)
            {
                for (int j = 1; j < tmpSheetArr.GetLength(1); j++)
                {
                    if (tmpMax < tmpSheetArr[i, j])
                        tmpMax = tmpSheetArr[i, j];
                }
            }


        cuts = null;  
        return tmpMax;   

    }
```

It doesn't work, gives too big results in some cases and gets stuck on bigger problems. I think the main problem is about going back - with only the weight stored I don't know what size of the block was used and if it will overlap with the current one.

I decided to write it from the beginning, but really can't find another approach. I have a code for the 1D problem:

```
        int cutRod(int[] price, int n)
    {
        int[] val = new int[n + 1];
        val[0] = 0;
        int i, j;

        // Build the table val[] and return the last entry
        // from the table
        for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        {
            int max_val = Int32.MinValue;
            for (j = 0; j < i; j++)
                max_val = Math.Max(max_val, price[j] + val[i - j - 1]);
            val[i] = max_val;
        }

        return val[n];
    }
```

How do I change it so it works for 2D problem?

I tried to explain my limited understanding and way of thinking the best I could. I would appreciate any help on this matter.

Comment: Could you please clarify the task with a small visual example? I have difficulty understanding it :)

Comment: There are no restrictions about how you are allowed to cut? If the only possible way to cut a rectangle is by a straight line, so that you again obtain two smaller rectangles, this seem analogous to the 1D problem. However, if you are allowed to cut a piece of wood into two arbitrarily shaped pieces, then the problem seems instantly more difficult.

Comment: So I actually misunderstood the task. It is the way you are describing. You can only make cuts by a straight line obtaining two smaller rectangles. However I still can't visualise how it is analogous to the 1D problem. I added the code for the 1D problem, how do I change it so it works for 2D?

Comment: Are you looking for this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47413384/cutting-algorithm-of-two-dimensional-board ?

Comment: It was not exactly the same problem, but it steered me in the right direction. I posted the solution in the answers. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution:

Build an array of maximum values that can be obtained from given piece of dimensions 1x1 up to the size of the board. Maximum value for given piece is stored under index of [(length of the piece) - 1, (width of the piece) - 1]. To find the maximum value, check how the current piece can be formed with previous pieces and cuts.

To construct the tree of cuts, build a second array of the best cuts for the current piece. Root of the cuts tree for the current piece is stored under index of [(length of the piece) - 1, (width of the piece) - 1].

Cuts class:

```
public class Cut
{

public int length;       // vertical dimension (before cut)
public int width;        // horizontal dimension (before cut)
public int price;        // sum of the values of the two elements resulting from the cut

public bool vertical;    // true for vertical cut, false otherwise
public int n;            // distance from left side (for vertical cut) or top (for horizontal cut) of the current piece
                         // price 0 means there was no cut, topleft and bottomright are null,

public Cut topleft;      // top/left resulting piece after cut
public Cut bottomright;  // bottom/right resulting piece after cut

public Cut(int length, int width, int price, bool vertical=true, int n=0, Cut topleft=null, Cut bottomright=null)
    {
    this.length = length;
    this.width = width;
    this.price = price;
    this.vertical = vertical;
    this.n = n;
    this.topleft = topleft;
    this.bottomright = bottomright;
    }

}
```

Function finding the maximum value and a tree of cuts:

```
        public int Cut((int length, int width) sheet, (int length, int width, int price)[] elements, out Cut cuts)
    {
        int[,] sheetArr = new int[sheet.length, sheet.width];   //contains best values of current pieces that can be formed
        Cut[,] cutsArr = new Cut[sheet.length, sheet.width];    //contains references for cuts used to form pieces of the best value,

        for (int l = 0; l < sheet.length; l++)   //loop on length
        {
            for (int w = 0; w < sheet.width; w++)    //loop on width
            {
                foreach ((int length, int width, int price) elem in elements)   //loop on elements
                {
                    if (elem.length == l + 1 && elem.width == w + 1)    //check if current piece can be build with one of the given elements
                    {
                        sheetArr[l, w] = elem.price;
                        cutsArr[l, w] = new Cut(elem.length, elem.width, elem.price);   //piece is exactly one of the elements (no cut)
                        break;  //no 2 elements of the same size in the given elements
                    }
                    cutsArr[l, w] = new Cut(l + 1, w + 1, 0);    //piece can not be formed from given elements, price = 0 (no cut)
                }

                for (int i = 1; i < Math.Floor((decimal)(l + 1) / 2) + 1; i++)  //go back on length
                {
                    if (sheetArr[i - 1, w] + sheetArr[l - i, w] > sheetArr[l, w])
                    {
                        sheetArr[l, w] = sheetArr[i - 1, w] + sheetArr[l - i, w];

                        cutsArr[l, w] = new Cut(l + 1, w + 1, sheetArr[l, w], false, i, cutsArr[i - 1, w], cutsArr[l - i, w]);
                    }
                }

                for (int i = 1; i < Math.Floor((decimal)(w + 1) / 2) + 1; i++)  //go back on width
                {
                    if (sheetArr[l, i - 1] + sheetArr[l, w - i] > sheetArr[l, w])
                    {
                        sheetArr[l, w] = sheetArr[l, i - 1] + sheetArr[l, w - i];

                        cutsArr[l, w] = new Cut(l + 1, w + 1, sheetArr[l, w], true, i, cutsArr[l, i - 1], cutsArr[l, w - i]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        cuts = cutsArr[sheet.length - 1, sheet.width - 1];
        return sheetArr[sheet.length - 1, sheet.width - 1];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Make your dynamic state at `x` be a dictionary mapping a particular "skyline" of what blocks placed before `x` look like after `x`.  You start with a flat skyline (no blocks so far, clean edge), and you're looking for a flat skyline at the other end (didn't go off the edge of the sheet).

As you advance you "lower" your skyline by 1, start looking at ways to cut out new blocks, and get new possible skylines.

The number of possible skylines will grow exponentially with the width of the rectangle.

Comment: It turned out I misunderstood the problem at first, so that it was more difficult. I don't understand your solution, but it might have been correct for that task, which was that you were allowed to cut a piece of sheet into two arbitrarily shaped pieces. Thank you anyway!